# How can we add AWS IOT credential to TensorFlow Lite Project on ESP IDF

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, esp-idf

How Should I integrate AWS FreeRTOS , TensorFlow Lite and ESP IDF together.
I have working code of TensorFlow Lite and a different code of amazon FreeRTOS that give message to AWS Test Client.

I am not able to integrate them together.

Amazon FreeRTOS from : https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos

TensorFlow Lite From : https://github.com/espressif/tensorflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to integrate them together"?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon FreeRTOS currently doesn't run together with ESP-IDF. ESP-IDF provides it's own version of FreeRTOS, mainly due to the lack of simultaneous multi processing capabilities of the original Amazon FreeRTOS. However, for high-level application code, it shouldn't matter too much and you should be able to port AWS FreeRTOS applications to ESP-IDF with reasonable effort.

Hence, it's probably best if you port both your messaging application as well as your TensorFlow Lite application to ESP-IDF. Once both are running, you can integrate them together.